# Unity 3D interaction with UI Image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am creating a 3D game and in the UI, there is an image that I want to print different things when the user puts the cursor on different parts of the Image. In a 2D game, I would add child objects to the image and add polygon colliders to them, and use OnMouseOver() method. But as I understand, this doesn't work on UI. I also tried OnPointerEnter() method and it works but I can't split the image into different parts using this. I tried to split the image into small parts using an external tool and putting them side by side and making a whole image but Unity recognizes all images as rectangular images (I am trying to make this for Girl with a Pearl Earring painting so shapes are irregular. ). How can I do this?

Comment: It would probably be easier to use a mesh with the different parts of the image so that each has its own collider, and give them a Texture material

Comment: Just use invisible panels or images with no image in them and alpha at 0 for your mouseover events. Make sure they're lower in the heirarchy i,e, sitting over the images you will display

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the best solution, you can get the current mouse position and check first if it's "inside" the picture, and then check for different parts
(For example if the image is between [100,100] to [300,300], and one part is between [100,100] to [150,150], you can check if the mouse is between those coordinates).

So you would get the position:

```
Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
float x1 = imageBoundry, x2 = imageBoundry;
float y1 = //Same but Y
if mousePosition.X between x1 and x2 && mousePosition.Y between y1 and y2
{
    Check, in which part of the image the cursor is at, and decide then
}
```

Or, you can raycast and check the tag, and if the tag matches to the image's one, check for the specific part

```
 ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
 if(Physics.Raycast(ray, hit))
 {
     if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag(YOUR_TAG))
     {
         Check for inner boundaries.
     }
 }
```